# multicast/worker queue with Tibco

Tags: tibco-ems

Does tibco support "multicast" ?

I guess another term used is "worker queues". (as seen in the rabbitmq link below)

See : http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html

I call them "fighters", as in, several processes can be wired to one queue, and when a message arrives in the queue, ONE of the several processes will get the message,but not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EMS and most JMS based messaging system (supporting Queues and Topics), this is ALREADY the default behavior.

In would not call that "multicast" or "worker queues", but simply "load sharing" or "load balancing". Active-Mq calls it "Clustering" (I don't like the term, but [the diagram is neat](http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html)).

The official name for the pattern is "[Competing consumers (EIP)](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CompetingConsumers.html)".

Whatever you call it, it's super easy to do in EMS. By default, queue accept multiple clients for reading (you can change this and make them exclusive, [see the user doc](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.3.0/doc/pdf/TIB_ems_8.3_users_guide.pdf)). When a queue is read by 2 or more consumers, and a message is sent to the queue, the message will go to one of ANY consumers. Hence your expected behavior.

Please refer to [the same link](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.3.0/doc/pdf/TIB_ems_8.3_users_guide.pdf) for another chapter (14, page 411) on "Multicast" with EMS. This is different... it's [ACTUAL NETWORK BASED Multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast), meant for helping lowering network traffic when a topic does publications to a massive amount of subscribers.

FYI, EMS is only one out of three messaging solution from TIBCO. The other two are Rendez-vous(older, UDP based) and FTL (newer, low latency solution).